# Can one quantify how well a finite subset of a Polish space approximates the whole space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite Polish space, and let $\mathcal{F}(X)$ be the set of all non-empty finite subsets of $X$.

> Does there exist a function $e \colon \mathcal{F}(X) \to (0,\infty)$ with the property that for any $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in X^\mathbb{N}$,
> $$ e(\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}) \to 0\, \text{ as } n \to \infty \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \{x_n : n \geq 1\} \text{ is dense in } X\,\text{?} $$

**Remark.** If $X$ is assumed to be $\sigma$-locally compact then I believe the answer is yes: taking $(K_n)_{n \geq 1}$ to be a sequence of compact subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, and fixing a bounded metrisation $d$ of the topology on $X$, we set
$$ e(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} d_\mathrm{HS}(K_n,A) $$
where $d_\mathrm{HS}(A_1,A_2) := \sup_{x \in A_1} \inf_{y \in A_2} d(x,y)$. But my intuition is that in general the answer is no. (This intuition comes partly from thinking about the last theorem in the paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035586, although the question being addressed there is not exactly the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the answer is fairly straightforwardly yes in general: if $\{U_n\}$ is a countable base, then let
$$ e(A) = \sum_n 2^{-n} \chi(U_n \cap A = \emptyset)$$
where $\chi$ assigns $1$ to a true statement and $0$ to a false statement.